# Javascript - Dynamically generate span IDs after styling radio buttons

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. I'm trying to do a show/hide on the "activationframe" and "equipmentframe" divs based on a radio button selection. I had it working fine but then the client decided to add styled radio buttons to the equation. That has broken my show/hide toggle. How do I incorporate that into the styled radio button JS?

Here is the styled radio buttons script:

```
var checkboxHeight = "25";
var radioHeight = "25";
var selectWidth = "190";

document.write('<style type="text/css">input.styled { display: none; } select.styled { position: relative; width: ' + selectWidth + 'px; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); z-index: 5; } .disabled { opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50); }</style>');

var Custom = {
init: function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), span = Array(), textnode, option, active;
    for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
        if((inputs[a].type == "radio") && inputs[a].className == "styled") {
            span[a] = document.createElement("span");
            span[a].className = inputs[a].type;

            if(inputs[a].checked == true) {
                    position = "0 -" + (radioHeight*2) + "px";
                    span[a].style.backgroundPosition = position;
                }
            inputs[a].parentNode.insertBefore(span[a], inputs[a]);
            inputs[a].onchange = Custom.clear;
            if(!inputs[a].getAttribute("disabled")) {
                span[a].onmousedown = Custom.pushed;
                span[a].onmouseup = Custom.check;
            } else {
                span[a].className = span[a].className += " disabled";
            }
        }
    }
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
        if(inputs[a].className == "styled") {
            option = inputs[a].getElementsByTagName("option");
            active = option[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            textnode = document.createTextNode(active);
            for(b = 0; b < option.length; b++) {
                if(option[b].selected == true) {
                    textnode = document.createTextNode(option[b].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                }
            }
            span[a] = document.createElement("span");
            span[a].className = "select";
            span[a].id = "select" + inputs[a].name;
            span[a].appendChild(textnode);
            inputs[a].parentNode.insertBefore(span[a], inputs[a]);
            if(!inputs[a].getAttribute("disabled")) {
                inputs[a].onchange = Custom.choose;
            } else {
                inputs[a].previousSibling.className = inputs[a].previousSibling.className += " disabled";
            }
        }
    }
    document.onmouseup = Custom.clear;
},
pushed: function() {
    element = this.nextSibling;
    if(element.checked == true && element.type == "radio") {
        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*3 + "px";
    } else {
        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight + "px";
    }
},
check: function() {
    element = this.nextSibling;
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*2 + "px";
            group = this.nextSibling.name;
            inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
                if(inputs[a].name == group && inputs[a] != this.nextSibling) {
                    inputs[a].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
        }
        element.checked = true;
    }
},
clear: function() {
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var b = 0; b < inputs.length; b++) {
        if(inputs[b].type == "radio" && inputs[b].checked == true && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*2 + "px";
        } else if(inputs[b].type == "radio" && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
        }
    }
},
choose: function() {
    option = this.getElementsByTagName("option");
    for(d = 0; d < option.length; d++) {
        if(option[d].selected == true) {
            document.getElementById("select" + this.name).childNodes[0].nodeValue = option[d].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
}
window.onload = Custom.init;
```

Here is my old script that does the show/hide:

```
function showhideInstall(installtype) {
if (installtype == "equipmentswap") {
    document.getElementById("activationframe").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("equipmentframe").style.display = 'block';
} else {
    document.getElementById("activationframe").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("equipmentframe").style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

And finally, my HTML:

```
<div id="activationtoggle">
            <form class="radiobuttons">
                <input type="radio" name="installtype" value="activation" class="styled" onclick="showhideInstall(this.value);" checked>&nbsp;&nbsp;New Activation
                <input type="radio" name="installtype" value="equipmentswap" class="styled" onclick="showhideInstall(this.value);" >&nbsp;&nbsp;Equipment Swap
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="activationframe">
            <div id="activationchecklist">
                    code here
                 </div>

             <div id="equipmentframe">
                <div id="equipmentswap">
                <h2>Equipment Swap</h2>
               more code here
                 </div>
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I'm middling at JS (at best) and this has proven to be a giant time sink.

Comment: add a counter to pushed: function() {

Comment: Please post relevant set of codes that describes/extends the question.

Comment: you are unlikely to get any help unless you make it easy to identify the problem and make sure that your questions are specific.

Comment: I have simplified the question a bit in an attempt to tackle one problem at a time.

Comment: just debug it. for example this line is suspicious: inputs[a].previousSibling.className = inputs[a].previousSibling.className += " disabled";

Comment: Thanks, all, but I figured it out. I thank you for the help, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a friend help  me resolve the problem, thanks for the help, everyone.

Here is the JS he supplied me with:

```
    function showhideInstall(installtype) {
    if (installtype == "equipmentswap") {
        document.getElementById("activationframe").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("equipmentframe").style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("activationframe").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("equipmentframe").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function newactivation( indexNum ) {

    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
    for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {

        if( inputs[a].id == "activation" + indexNum ){
            inputs[a].style.color = "#b5b5b5";  
        }
    }

    var activechecked = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i<= 7; i++) {
        if(document.getElementById("activationcheck" + i).checked == true){
            activechecked ++;
        }else if(document.getElementById("activationnocheck" + i).checked == true){
            activechecked ++;
        }
  }

  if (activechecked <= 6) {document.getElementById("next").disabled= true;}
  if (activechecked == 7) {document.getElementById("next").disabled= false; document.getElementById("next").style.cursor= "pointer"; } 
}
function equipmentswap( indexNum ) {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
    for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {

        if( inputs[a].id == "equip" + indexNum ){
            inputs[a].style.color = "#b5b5b5";
            a=inputs.length + 1;        
        }
    }

    var activechecked = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i<= 7; i++) {
        if(document.getElementById("swapcheck" + i).checked == true){
            activechecked ++;
        }else if(document.getElementById("swapnocheck" + i).checked == true){
            activechecked ++;
        }
  }

  if (activechecked <= 6) {document.getElementById("equipnext").disabled= true;}
  if (activechecked == 7) {document.getElementById("equipnext").disabled= false; document.getElementById("next").style.cursor= "pointer"; }
}
```